# creating @morerows attribute in the 'entry' element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to add @morerows attribute in the 'entry' element. If you see in the input has `<vmerge val="restart"/>` and in the next `<tr>/<tc>` has `<vmerge/>` then total number of `<vmerge>` should be `@morerows` attribute value, Please look expected output.
Please help me on this and it's very grateful for me.

**Input:**

```
<tbl>
    <tblGrid>
        <gridCol/>
        <gridCol/>
    </tblGrid>
    <tr>
        <tc>
            <p>Content Here</p>
        </tc>
        <tc>
            <tcPr>
                <vmerge val="restart"/>
            </tcPr>
            <p>Content here</p>
        </tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc>
            <p>Contenet here</p>
        </tc>
        <tc>
            <tcPr>
                <vmerge/>
            </tcPr>
            <p>Content here</p>
        </tc>
    </tr>
</tbl>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<table>
    <tgroup rowsep="0" cols="2">
        <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="24.94*"/>
        <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="25.06*"/>
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry align="left">
                    <p>content here</p>
                </entry>
                <entry morerows="" align="right">
                    <p>Contenet here</p>
                </entry>
            </row>
            <row>
                <entry align="left">
                    <p></p>
                </entry>
                <entry align="left">
                    <p></p>
                </entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
```

Comment: @Vasyl Krupa, please can you help me on above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the rule correctly - you need to count *tc* elements with tcPr/vmerge in the same row that have preceding vmerge val="restart".

The following code should work for you:

```
<xsl:template match="tc">
    <entry>
        <!-- morerows rule -->
        <xsl:if test="tcPr/vmerge[@val='restart']">
            <xsl:variable name="currentTcPosition" select="count(preceding-sibling::tc) + 1"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vmergeId" select="generate-id(tcPr/vmerge)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="followingTcRow" select="parent::tr/following-sibling::tr/tc[position() = $currentTcPosition]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="morerowsValue" select="count($followingTcRow/tcPr/vmerge[not(@val='restart')][preceding::vmerge[@val='restart'][1][generate-id(.) = $vmergeId]]) + 1"/>

            <xsl:attribute name="morerows" select="$morerowsValue"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

This is output that I got with attached input:

```
<table>
<tgroup rowsep="0" cols="2">
    <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="24.94*"/>
    <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="25.06*"/>
    <tbody>
        <row>
    <entry>Content Here</entry>
    <entry morerows="2">Content here</entry>
</row>
<row>
    <entry>Contenet here</entry>
    <entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
    </tbody>
</tgroup></table>
```

Please note that if you need to ignore empty entries with tcPr/vmerge (without @val='restart' attribute) you can create empty template for them:

```
<xsl:template match="tc[tcPr/vmerge[not(@val='restart')]]"/>
```

Below you can see an example with a more complex table (without ignoring entries with tcPr/vmerge without @val='restart' attribute).

Test input:

```
<tbl>
<tblGrid>
    <gridCol/>
    <gridCol/>
</tblGrid>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>Content Here</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <vmerge val="restart"/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>Contenet here</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <vmerge/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>Contenet here</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>Content Here</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <vmerge val="restart"/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>Contenet here</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <vmerge/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>Contenet here</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <vmerge/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>Contenet here</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <p>Content here</p>
    </tc>
</tr></tbl>
```

Test output:

```
<table>
<tgroup rowsep="0" cols="2">
    <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="24.94*"/>
    <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="25.06*"/>
    <tbody>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Content Here
            </entry>
            <entry morerows="2">
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Contenet here
            </entry>
            <entry>
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Contenet here
            </entry>
            <entry>
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Content Here
            </entry>
            <entry morerows="3">
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Contenet here
            </entry>
            <entry>
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Contenet here
            </entry>
            <entry>
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Contenet here
            </entry>
            <entry>
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
    </tbody>
</tgroup></table>
```